# Bootstrapper exe does not use uninstall of msi

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bundler, uninstallation, bootstrapper

I have added custom dialog in msi that allows to uninstall user's files. If I install msi everything works perfect when uninstalling and i can see my custom dialog window. But if i install my app through bundle.exe (bundle installs framework if needed and msi itself), during uninstalling  it makes silent uninstall (just drop files) and no dialog window I can see. What problem can it be and how to solve it? It is really important for me, because end user will use bundle. Waiting for your answer...

Here is bundle

```
<Bundle Name="$(var.ProductName)" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="License.rtf"/>
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>


<Chain>
  <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist"/>

  <MsiPackage Id="Synchronizer" SourceFile="$(var.Installer.TargetPath)" DisplayInternalUI="yes" After="NetFx40Redist" />
</Chain>
```

Comment: Your using standard UI + your custom dialog? have you changed on every standard UI reference to your dialog?

Comment: @Buzka91 Yes, I use standard ui +custom dialog. What do you mean under changed on every standard UI reference to your dialog? I changed in wix_ui wixard references to my dialog. It works fine if i install msi file, but i use bootstrapper, which installs framework, sql server and this msi itself and this bootsrtapper does not use uninstall logics of msi